# Python ImportError with import from different folders

Tags: python, package, python-import

I'm following this guide to learn how to structure a good project: [Structuring Your Project](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/#test-suite). And I'm having problems about importing modules from different folders. My project is structured as follows:

```
project
│   .gitignore
│   LICENSE
│   Makefile
│   README.md
│
├───project
│       main.py
│       __init__.py
│
└───tests
        context.py
        var_class.py
        __init__.py
```

In `main.py` I have

```
# main.py

class Var():
    pass
```

In `context.py` I've followed the guide cited above, so I have:

```
# context.py

import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))

import project
```

In `var_class.py` I have:

```
# var_class.py

from .context import project

x = project.main.Var()
```

Running the last one I obtain:

```
$ python var_class.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Matteo\Documents\project\tests\var_class.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .context import pierre
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks to everyone who will help me.

Comment: Try adding an `__init__.py` to the parent `project` folder. It's trying to import `context` from its parent package, which doesn't exist.

Comment: @koorkevani it didn't solve the problem, same error occurred

Comment: Try changing the line to `from ..context import project` (while keeping the `__init__.py`)

Comment: @koorkevani still having same problem

Comment: found the problem. `__init__.py` is not needed, nor is the double-period. You do need, however, to run it with the `-m` flag to tell python there's a local module hierarchy. Enter your top `project` dir, then `python3 -m tests.var_class` (or the dir above the top `project`, and `python3 -m project.tests.var_class`). There's still an error, but it happens because `project/__init__.py` doesn't automatically import `main`. Add to it the line `from . import main` and you're done.

Comment: @koorkevani this now seems to work. Anyway after it executes the code it also prints: ```C:\Users\Matteo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe: Error while finding module specification for 'tests.var_class.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: __path__ attribute not found on 'tests.var_class' while trying to find 'tests.var_class.py'). Try using 'tests.var_class' instead of 'tests.var_class.py' as the module name.```